# Trying to make a jQuery like with multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, helper

I try to make a very lite "jQuery like" selector, but I have problem to make it work on all classes, I tried with a for loop but because of the "return new" it brakes the loop.

JS

```
var $ = function(el){       
  var helpers = {
    css: function(v){
      (this.value).setAttribute('style',v);     
    },
    replace: function(v){
      (this.value).innerHTML = v;
      console.log(this.value);
    },
    append: function(v){
      (this.value).innerHTML =  (this.value).outerHTML + ' ' + v;
    }
  };
  function sel(el){ 
    this.value = document.querySelector(el);
  }
  sel.prototype = helpers;
  return new sel(el);
};

var sel1 = $('.sel1');

sel1.replace('<span>replaced</span>');
sel1.css("color:red");
```

HTML

```
<div class="sel1">test</div>
<div class="sel1">test</div>
<div class="sel1">test</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd bother using a class but if you do please name it with an initial capital letter.

Comment: But `sel` is being used as a constructor

Comment: There's multiple problems -- you are using `css()` wrong, you're overwriting jQuery rather than extending it, but why are you even trying to extend it in the first place? Why not simply use `$('.sel1').css("color", "red");`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad—Hmm, the formatting made me miss the *new*, fixed. Can't find the *for* loop though…

Comment: To select multiple matches, use `querySelectorAll`. This means that `this.value` will be array-like and you'll need to deal with it as an array-like object. Also, your `append` function is using `outerHTML` where it should (presumably) use `innerHTML`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, no, he clearly said he was rewriting his own lite version of jQuery. It's not jQuery at all.

Comment: Exactly, I don't want to use a 300kb only for selectors. It will be great to use something really lite for this purpose. Thanks for all your comments!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the matches and not just the very first one. That's what jQuery does.

Obviously, this means 'value' is not a node, instead, it's a `NodeList` (or `null`). This changes the functions because they all have to deal with a list so you have to have some form of `foreach()` to apply your function to each node (which, again, is what jQuery does, see the [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) function as a good proof of this.)

Finally, if nothing matches, jQuery gets a null and the functions still work. This is because each function uses the `foreach()` function and on `null`, `foreach()` does nothing. So you'd have to implement that `foreach()`. Maybe something like this:

```
function foreach(list, func)
{
   var max, i, n;

   if(list) // make sure list is not 'null'
   {
       max = list.length;
       for(i = 0; i < max; ++i) // go through the elements
       {
           n = list[i];
           func(n);   // call user function
       }
   }
}
```

Then the `css` function would become something like this:

```
css: function(v)
{
  foreach(this.value, function(n) { n.setAttribute('style', v); });
}
```

**Note:** if you make the `foreach()` part of the helpers, make sure to use `this.foreach()` to call it.

Comment: Good answer. Please consider amending your code style to place opening braces on the same line as the construct that necessitates them. This is standard in JavaScript and not doing so can lead to issues, for example it will fail when returning an object literal.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, my project has 45,000 lines of JavaScript and I'm fine with the `{` where I put them... I'm not too sure why your stuff  would fail, JavaScript is not line agnostic at all.

Answer (score 0):

One of the powers of jQuery is the possibility to chain commands, which is actually done by holding a reference to the initial selector query. To get the basic idea, a simple kick-start implementation could look like this:

```
$$$ = function(selector) {
  var Handler = function(selector) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    this.css = function(options) {
      for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        for (var property in options) {
          elements.item(i).style[property] = options[property];
        }
      }
      return this;
    };
    this.hide = function() {
      return this.css({display: 'none'});
    };
    this.show = function() {
      return this.css({display: ''});
    };
    this.replace = function(html) {
      for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        elements.item(i).innerHTML = html;
      };
      return this;
    };
  };
  return new Handler(selector);
};
```

A simple working example for the code above could look like this:

```
$$$('div').css({border: '1px solid red', background: 'green'}).hide().show();
```

Since all internal functions return the current instance (`return $this`), chaining calls to different actions is enabled.

Comment: From what I've seen, the `elements.forEach()` is not available in IE... Would that work in IE 11?

Comment: Alexis, thanks for the hint, I've replaced the `Array.prototype.forEach` calls with plain `for()` iterations. MDN states, `forEach` is available since IE9, however only MSDN mentions, that that's only the case in standard mode, not in quirks mode - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679980(v=vs.94).aspx